# Rust: Multithreading ImageData WebAssembly

Tags: multithreading, image-processing, rust, webassembly

I would like to improve my rust code in Webassembly with multithreading. Unfortunatly I am not an expert in Rust and have some problems.

My code looks currently like this:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn box_blur_1d(context: CanvasRenderingContext2d,x: usize, y: usize, width: usize, height: usize) -> Clamped<Vec<u8>> {
    let i_data = context.get_image_data(0.0,0.0,1280.0,720.0).unwrap();
    let mut data: Clamped<Vec<u8>> = i_data.data();

    for row in y..y+height {
        blur_row(&mut data, row, x, width);
    }
    
    for column in x..x+width {
        blur_column(&mut data, column, y, height);
    }
    return data;
}
```

What is my Code doing?

### In general my code puts a box_blur effect on an image.

- Save the Pixels in a Clamped<Vec> called data
- for each row: manipulate the data of the row
- for each column: manipulate the data of the column
- Return the data

### Where do I have problems?

- I cant manipulate the same data from different threads

I tried to implement the Rust standard library : https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html
I tried to implement it with the rayon library. Unfortunatly my rust skills arent good enough yet.

Maybe you also have tips for me on how to improve the performance of the program. If you also need some informations about the blur_row & blur_column functions here they are:

```
pub fn blur_row(data: &mut Clamped<Vec<u8>>, row: usize, x: usize, width: usize) {
    let mut r: usize = 0;
    let mut g: usize = 0;
    let mut b: usize = 0;
    let rowPosition: usize = row * 1280 * 4;

    let min: isize = x as isize - deviationBase as isize;

    for column in max(min,0) as usize..(x+deviationBase+1) {
        r += data[rowPosition + column * 4   ] as usize;
        g += data[rowPosition + column * 4 +1] as usize;
        b += data[rowPosition + column * 4 +2] as usize;
    }

    data[rowPosition + 0 + x * 4] = (r / (deviationBase + 1)) as u8;
    data[rowPosition + 1 + x * 4] = (g / (deviationBase + 1)) as u8;
    data[rowPosition + 2 + x * 4] = (b / (deviationBase + 1)) as u8;

    for column in x+1..deviationBase {
        r += data[rowPosition + (column + deviationBase) * 4    ] as usize;
        g += data[rowPosition + (column + deviationBase) * 4 + 1] as usize; 
        b += data[rowPosition + (column + deviationBase) * 4 + 2] as usize;
        data[rowPosition + column * 4    ] = (r / (diameter - deviationBase + column)) as u8;
        data[rowPosition + column * 4 + 1] = (g / (diameter - deviationBase + column)) as u8;
        data[rowPosition + column * 4 + 2] = (b / (diameter - deviationBase + column)) as u8;
    }

    for column in max(deviationBase, x+1)..x+width-deviationBase {
        r += data[rowPosition + (column + deviationBase) * 4    ] as usize;
        g += data[rowPosition + (column + deviationBase) * 4 + 1] as usize;
        b += data[rowPosition + (column + deviationBase) * 4 + 2] as usize;
        r -= data[rowPosition + (column - deviationBase) * 4    ] as usize; 
        g -= data[rowPosition + (column - deviationBase) * 4 + 1] as usize;
        b -= data[rowPosition + (column - deviationBase) * 4 + 2] as usize;
    
        data[rowPosition + column * 4    ] = (r / diameter) as u8;
        data[rowPosition + column * 4 + 1] = (g / diameter) as u8;
        data[rowPosition + column * 4 + 2] = (b / diameter) as u8;
    }

    for column in x+width-deviationBase..x+width {
        r -= data[rowPosition + (column- deviationBase) * 4    ] as usize;
        g -= data[rowPosition + (column- deviationBase) * 4 + 1] as usize;
        b -= data[rowPosition + (column- deviationBase) * 4 + 2] as usize;
        data[rowPosition + column * 4    ] = (r / (deviationBase + x + width - column)) as u8;
        data[rowPosition + column * 4 + 1] = (g / (deviationBase + x + width - column)) as u8;
        data[rowPosition + column * 4 + 2] = (b / (deviationBase + x + width - column)) as u8;
    }
}

pub fn blur_column(data: &mut Clamped<Vec<u8>>, column: usize, y: usize, height: usize) {
    let mut r: usize = 0;
    let mut g: usize = 0;
    let mut b: usize = 0;

    let columnPosition: usize = column*4;

    let min: isize = y as isize - deviationBase as isize;
    for row in max(min, 0) as usize..y+deviationBase+1 {
        r += data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 0] as usize; 
        g += data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 1] as usize; 
        b += data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 2] as usize; 
    }
    data[columnPosition + 0 + y * 1280 * 4] = (r/(deviationBase+1)) as u8;
    data[columnPosition + 1 + y * 1280 * 4] = (g/(deviationBase+1)) as u8;
    data[columnPosition + 2 + y * 1280 * 4] = (b/(deviationBase+1)) as u8;

    for row in y+1..deviationBase {
        r += data[(row + deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition    ] as usize;
        g += data[(row + deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 1] as usize; 
        b += data[(row + deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 2] as usize;
        data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition    ] =  (r / (diameter - deviationBase + row)) as u8;
        data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 1] =  (g / (diameter - deviationBase + row)) as u8;
        data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 2] =  (b / (diameter - deviationBase + row)) as u8;
    }

    for row in max(deviationBase, y+1)..y+height-deviationBase {
        r += data[(row + deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition   ] as usize;
        g += data[(row + deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition +1] as usize; 
        b += data[(row + deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition +2] as usize;
        r -= data[(row - deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition   ] as usize;
        g -= data[(row - deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition +1] as usize;
        b -= data[(row - deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition +2] as usize;

        data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition    ] = (r / diameter) as u8;
        data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 1] = (g / diameter) as u8;
        data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 2] = (b / diameter) as u8;
    }

    for row in y+height-deviationBase..y+height {
        r -= data[(row - deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition   ] as usize;
        g -= data[(row - deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition +1] as usize;
        b -= data[(row - deviationBase) * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition +2] as usize;
        data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition    ] = (r / (deviationBase + y + height - row)) as u8;
        data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 1] = (g / (deviationBase + y + height - row)) as u8;
        data[row * 1280 * 4 + columnPosition + 2] = (b / (deviationBase + y + height - row)) as u8;
    }
}
```